# Kibana Import in Saved Objects?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

[Kibana Saved Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYmAJ.png)

What is this Import button used for? Importing Data? Like CSV files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button `export everything` in `Management` panel will export all datas you created in Kibana, like dashboards, visualizations and searches. The out put data is a json file including datas the visualizations/search/dashboard made. When you import the json file you will get all the visualizations/search/dashboard you made ,and you don't need to make them again.

It's useful when you upgraded your kibana or your kibana is shut down unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

That import button is for importing saved objects, such as dashboards, visualizations and searches. The idea behind this is when you design a dashboard in your development environment, you don't want to redesign everything anew in your production Kibana when your dahsboard are ready.

So what you usually do is to export your dashboards + visualizations + saved searches from your dev Kibana and import them into your other Kibanas running in other environments.